# How do I quit a qt console application? Are there criterions for the QApplication::quit() slot to work?

Tags: qt, console-application, quit

I have a weird qt problem: My application doesn't quit in some configurations.

The idea is to have a program, which can be started as a program with a GUI (through `myWindow`) or as a pure console application (controlled via `myConsole`, which runs its own loop in its thread to record keyboard inputs). Either way quitting is done by calling the `myObject` slot `quitMyObject`, which in turn cleans up some objects and emits the signal `signalQuitapplication`, which is connected to the `QApplication` (`app`) `quit` slot.

Unfortunately the application only quits when the the window is enabled and the quit command is entered in the console (although the `slotQuitMyObject`  of `myObject`  is always called). So I wonder what criterions Qt has to actually quit the main event loop and exit the program.

The code looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    bool enableWindow = false;
    QApplication app(argc, argv, enableWindow);
    MyUiAbstract* myConsole = new ConsoleUi(); // ConsoleUi inherits from MyUiAbstract, which inherits from QThread
    MyWindow* myWindow = NULL; // MyWindow inherits from QMainWindow
    if(enableWindow)
    {
        myWindow = new MyWindow();
        myWindow->show();
    }

     MyObject* myObject = new MyObject(myConsole, myWindow, ...); 

     QObject::connect(myObject, SIGNAL(signalQuitQApplication()), &app, SLOT(quit()), Qt::QueuedConnection);

     QObject::connect(myConsole, SIGNAL(signalQuitMyObject()), myObject, SLOT(slotQuitMyObject()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
     QObject::connect(myWindow, SIGNAL(signalQuitMyObject()), myObject, SLOT(slotQuitMyObject()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
     QObject::connect(myWindow, SIGNAL(signalQuitConsoleUI()), myConsole, SLOT(slotQuitMyUi()), Qt::QueuedConnection);

     return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Does all your connections succeed? You will see warnings in runtime, if any failed.

Comment: wellll, there was a typo `signalQuitQApplication` vs `signalQuitApplication`, that hurt... now the only non-working thing is quitting the program from the GUI (strangely enough it works, if the debugger is on).

Comment: Ok, I figured out the second bug: a call to `getline(...)` blocked the console thread... I 'brutally' solved this by terminating the thread, as there doesn't seem to be a simple and clean solution (s.o. else had that problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408584/problem-with-getline-and-threads). The window is only for testing, so I think this is ok...

Answer (score -1):

Try to use that code in your MyConsole class:

```
#include <QApplication>
...
qApp->quit();
```

Also you need to close all the event loops & threads before quit.

Comment: I can't call "qApp->quit" from "myConsole", because the applications central "myObject" needs to clean up all its objects first. Maybe I could make the call from the "myObject" directly, if I store the "qApp" as a member...

Comment: hm... having the qApp as a member does not seem to be intended by qt... How did you intend me to make "qapp" known to my object?... Besides this: `QObject::connect(myObject, SIGNAL(signalQuitQApplication()), &app, SLOT(quit()), Qt::DirectConnection);` should have the same effect and it doesn't help.

Comment: Does your code like this:
class MyConsole: public QThread {
    Q_OBJECT
protected:
    virtual void run();
signals:
    void quitSignal();
};

void MyConsole::run() {
    int i = 1;
    while (true) {
        std::cin >> i;
        if (i == 0) {
            emit quitSignal();
        }
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    bool enableWindow = false;
    QApplication app(argc, argv, enableWindow);
    MyConsole* myConsole = new MyConsole();
    QObject::connect(myConsole, SIGNAL(quitSignal()), &app, SLOT(quit()));
    myConsole->start();
    return app.exec();
}

Comment: similar, though i leave the infinite loop before emitting the signal... anyway, the problem mostly seemed to be a nasty typo now only quitting from the GUI doesn't work (see above), I apologize... I thought the compiler would catch such things :-/

Comment: Unfortunately not. In runtime you can get such warnings as: 'Object::connect: No such signal MyConsole::qui1tSignal()' or 'Object::connect: No such slot QApplication::quit1()'.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't look at the beginning of the output, because I have some other "debug" output in it... Thanks for your effort!

Comment: `connect(&obj, &hang::done, &app, &app::quit, Qt::QueuedConnection);` , maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141910/qcoreapplication-ignores-quit-signal-and-hangs will help.